# Can't load image using gdiplus lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+

I am trying to loag a gif image with `MFC C++` `gdiplus` lib using the function :

```
void CGIFControl::Load(LPCWSTR sFileName)
{
  //PLEASE MAKE SURE FILEPATH RIGHT!
  Image* m_pImage = Image::FromFile( sFileName );    
  ......
}
```

I have add this lines to my `StdAfx.h` file :

```
#include<gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
```

But the problem is my image `m_pImage` all the time returns null.

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you call [`GdiplusStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077(v=vs.85).aspx) before calling any other GDI+ functions?

Comment: Yes you have rigth, it was that my problem, i have add GdiplusStartupInput and now it's work, thank you so much!!